# What is difference between Mutex() and Mutex(true,"myMutex") Thread object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

I have code which creates multiple thread and all threads try to log the informaion in a single file
I try to use the mutex lock for logging into file but i get different response when i use `Mutex()` and `Mutex(true or false, "name")` object.
`Mutex()` gave proper expected result but `Mutex(true/false, "myname")` missing few log information.

So what is the difference between them?

```
System.Threading.Mutex mtx = new System.Threading.Mutex(false ,"Myname" );

try
{       
    try
    {
        mtx.WaitOne();
    }
    catch (AbandonedMutexException) 
    { }            

  //log into file
}

catch (Exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION CAUGHT ***");
}
finally
{
    mtx.ReleaseMutex();
    mtx.Close();               
}
```

Comment: You should have added a tag indicating the language you're using. From looking at the class names/namespaces, I assume you're using C#.

Comment: Have you tried the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx)?

Comment: [`Mutex()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/21sa3fy3.aspx) and [`Mutex(bool, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/f55ddskf.aspx)

Comment: See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf(v=vs.110).aspx - basically, a *named* mutex can be accessed from multiple places - including cross-process and even cross-user (if global). An anonymous mutex is unique and isolated

Comment: What log information is missing? Does your code demonstrate the writing of the log?

Comment: It's unlikely that the missing log information is a result of the way that you initialized the mutex. You should look elsewhere for your error.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of the [parameterless constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/21sa3fy3.aspx).

> Calling this constructor overload is the same as calling the Mutex(Boolean) constructor overload and specifying false for initial ownership of the mutex. That is, the calling thread does not own the mutex.

The second parameter only gives the mutex a name. So if, for example, another process creates a mutex with the same name, the existing mutex will be shared between those two processes.